# Design help for my 1A variable power supply

Tags: power-supply, power, transformer, diodes, rectifier

In a 1A Variable Power Supply circuit given below is it possible to use a 2A transformer and 1A bridge diodes. 
[image]

Comment: If all you ever draw is 1A, then in theory 1A diodes would be ok - but I wouldn't advise it. Depending on the transformer output, either D2 AND D3, or D1 AND D4 are conducting. Acting as 1A fuses. I'd cut back the transformer rating, increase the diodes, or both.

Comment: @AlanCampbell i am using 50V 1A 1N4001 Diode. Is it ok ?

Comment: Those are rated for average of 1A @ 75 degrees C (hot!) and non-repetitive surges up to 30A. In the event you accidentally short out your power supply, what will limit the amount of current you draw as things spark / melt / burn / trip fuses? ADD A FUSE to the mains side, 150mA to 200mA slow blow (more resistant to transients at switch on). In the event of a disaster, the 1N4001 will pass higher current, and the transformer will supply it - but the fuse will burn out.

Answer (score 1):

If your transformer can supply 2A, there will be circumstances that it will. If you have 1A diodes, they will probably fry.

I always make sure that any part of my circuit can handle the potential maximum values of voltage and current.

Comment: i am using 50V 1A 1N4001 Diode. Is it ok ?

Answer (score 0):

Which name of diode? Is 1A means in datasheet maximum half-cycle rectified AC? If so, then I think you can't use these diodes in your schematic.

Comment: i am using 50V 1A 1N4001 Diode. Is it ok ?